# How can I make a wizard swear something in a way that will bind them to their word?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard

I want to make an neutral evil wizard swear to be my teacher in exchange for saving his life. Is there a spell or something to make him keep his word? Are there options if he is from another spellcasting class, like sorcerer or warlock?

They are both Drow so I was thinking of making him swear to Lolth, but I don't think that would stop him from betraying me. This is only roleplay oriented, so that I can pick up a second class.

Comment: Never trust anyone who swears by the name of a god of trickery.

Comment: Hahaha, yeah you are rigth I forgot that detail.

Comment: What do you mean "this is only role oriented"? Do you mean roleplay related?

Comment: Yup, I want an excuse to have a second class.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a spell to make him keep his word: *Geas* (PHB, page 244.). It would probably break copyright for me to type it all out here, so I'll mention the important bits.

- *Geas* is a 5th-level spell available to most spellcasters that forces a target to carry out a task or command given at the time of casting.
- A *Geas* lasts a limited amount of time based on what level it is cast at (30 days at 5th level), or is permanent if cast at 9th level.
- *Geas* enforces itself by dealing 5d10 damage every day that the target doesn't follow the *Geas*.
- As a side effect, it also makes it impossible for the target to attack you. (Given that your intended target is evil, this might actually be *more* valuable than the main effect.)

If you can't cast *Geas* yourself, your best bet is probably to find the temple of a Lawful Good deity; a Cleric of such a deity should be willing to cast *Geas* to help you make them keep their word, although a donation to their temple might not go astray.

Comment: Bear in mind the target can choose to take the damage and cast Dispel Magic. The damage only happens once per day, so it's not really a very practical way to bind wizards if they can handle the damage.

Comment: As stated in the spell description, also Remove Curse, Greater Restoration or Wish also ends it. It is weird that if casted using a spell slot of 9th level, the spell "lasts until it is ended by one of the spells mentioned above". I wonder if Dispel Magic is still effective by RAW.

Comment: Create Thrall (level 14 GOOlock) might be a better way to do it. That way, the guy won't resent you, you can get telepathic instruction, and you know if the spell ends.

Comment: @Ethan Unfortunately Create Thrall doesn't actually make them do anything.

Comment: It wouldn't necessarily force him, but the advantage on charisma checks wouldn't hurt, and you'd at least know that he thinks he's your best friend. Probably at least as compelling as a geas that he could ignore without dying.

Comment: @Ethan You seem to be confusing "charmed" with *Charm Person*. Charmed is a condition from Appendix A of the PHB.

Comment: @Miniman Ah, didn't realize charm doesn't make the target actually like you technically.

Comment: I think Geas could work for a drow mage. They do not have dispel magic on their spell list, and while with typcial hp of 45 they survive 99.75% of times, this may not be a chance they want to take just to avoid teaching.

Comment: I'll add that it should be possible for the wizard to cast *geas* on himself, if he can cast 5th level spells and has it in his spellbook. Then you have no need to find a third party (unless you can't trust the wizard not to insert a loophole).

Answer (score 2):

I would think that the best way to get him to do this is to simply ask him.  You would have to roll against Persuasion to convince him, but he's Neutral Evil, so you'll have to convince him that it's in his best interest to do this.  In convincing him of this, he may require that you go on a quest to bring back a particular item or you could find out his motivation and offer that if you're also a wizard, your party would have a better chance of helping him acquire what he wants (This could give your DM an idea for your next campaign too).

Answer (score 1):

### You do not need teacher to pick up a second class; if your DM demands it, work with them

#### Rules as written

Multiclassing (p.163 PHB) is an optional rule that requires your DM's permission. It otherwise has the following conditions:

> ##### Prerequisites
>
> To qualify for a new class, **you must meet the ability score prerequisites** for both your current class and your new
> one, as shown in the Multiclassing Prerequisites table. (...) Without the full training that a beginning character receives, you must be a quick study in your new class, having a natural aptitude that
> is reflected by higher-than-average ability scores.

There are no other prerequisites, in particular there is no rule that states you need a teacher to train you in your new class. There is also the Multiclassing example of Gary the Fighter who wants to become a Rogue:

> Gary’s fighter has been spending a lot of time with Dave’s rogue, and has even been doing some jobs on the side for the local thieves’ guild as a bruiser. **Gary decides that his character will multiclass into the rogue class, and thus his character becomes** a 4th-level fighter and 1stlevel
> rogue

He decides. No training course at Rogue Academy involved.

#### Roleplaying the contract

Essentially this is something you should work out with your DM off the table. Do they want to allow you to take classes in wizard? If they do not want you to multiclass, no amount of roleplay, spells and tactics is going to make it work.

If they do, how can you work this into the story in a believable way? Because becoming a wizard normally involves long years of apprenticeship and study, it may be that your DM rules that you need a mentor to teach you, in this case the drow wizard. And he may want to leverage this relationship as a convenient way to send you on adventures and errands as an apprentice to this evil wizard, a classic trope.

If this evil drow wizard is how you agree to do do it, then you should not need to worry if they keep their word about it. **In-game, just play out that they swear on their soul or anything that is highly important to them.** Eventually, you will be a wizard in your own right, and then you can decide if you want to pay the drow wizard back for any abuse, or if you want to retain the relationship for mutual benefit.

#### Enforcing the contract

P.S. To force a wizard to keep their word in-game, the most surefire way might be to have them sign an infernal contract for their commitment (Monster Manual, page 66):

> Devils are crafty negotiators and positively ruthless at enforcing the terms of an agreement. Moreover, a contract with even the lowliest devil is enforced by Asmodeus's will. Any mortal creature that breaks such a contract instantly forfeits its soul, which is spirited away to the Nine Hells.

This sounds like a method much harder to wriggle out of than a mere *geas*. The question of course is what *you* have to sign up for to have your infernal attorney provide this service.

Comment: I disagree with the need for a frame challenge.  Of course you can just multiclass if you want, but the asker is clearly in the domain of roleplaying, not character building here.  That said, your P.S. is quite good.  I would even suggest that the infernal attorney's mere opportunity to possess the evil wizard's soul (and ability to temp him to do so) might be enough to enlist his service, although if this isn't enough, maybe including your own name in there, promising to be "a diligent student" and thus risking your own soul if you fail, might sweeten the pot.

Comment: @RichardWinters, Yes, you surely can roleplay the swearing part, in character. It will not by itself *force* the wizard to follow through, of course, and my thought is that it does not need to, enforcing it is overkill if both the DM and player want to this to happen anyways. For the infernal contact, I agree, entering the contract too with the option for two souls sounds like an attractive solution for the devil.

Comment: Multiclassing is a variant rule. A DM can run a RAW game that requires finding a trainer to multiclass

Comment: @Caleth, yes, I agree, it would not be surprisng that a DM adds such requirements. And if they do, but are OK with multiclassing otherwise (which as written does not need them), then you need to fulfill them. What I am trying to say is that the evil drow wizard here sounds exactly like a good opportunity for that, and may not need any coercion spells. It essentially is a tool for the DM to create adventure hooks, too.